# Write access to a database using Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, sql, database, visual-studio-2010

Please forgive me if I am somewhat vague on my question.  I am following an online [Tutorial](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/membership/creating-user-accounts-cs) which shows you how to create your own users, permissions, etc (within VS utilizing SQL).  The problem I am having comes when Visual Studio tries to write to the database file. I have successfully created the database and connected to it utilizing Visual Studio, but when I run the code I receive the following error:

> SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\username'

now, I have checked and checked my credentials on SQL and I can succesfully create new dbs, modify, etc.  I am truly lost at what the source of the problem might be, I have tried using different credentials to no avail! Is there a setting I must check within VS to give it admin rights to a database? I have tried so many different ways to solve this issue and have not found what I'm overlooking or doing wrong. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you!!!!!!!!

Comment: What is the code, and what have you tried?

Comment: Is this account a windows account or a sql account?

Comment: The account I'm trying to access it with is a Windows Authentication account.  I have tried changing the connectionStrings on my project to use a different user, but nothing. I have checked that SQL accepts remote connections. I have tried connecting to the database through VS Tools>Options>Database Tools>Data Connections, etc.

Comment: Is there a setting in VS 2010 that I can play with to test a connection to a DB?

Answer (score 2):

There are two things going on here:

1. The Membership users you want for your site, and
2. Accessing your SQL Server database

You need to provide a connection string to your database, where the `Membership` provider will store user data.  This username/password is not a user from your `Membership` datastore.  Based on the error you posted, it looks like your connection string is using `Integrated Security`, so it would look something like:

`Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;Integrated Security=SSPI;`

What you'll most likely want to do is setup a `SQL Server Login` to put in your connection string.  Good reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337562(v=sql.105).aspx

Once the login is created, you can change your connection string to use the username & password you created the login with.  Something like this:

`Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;
Password=myPassword;`

Comment: That sounds like something I haven't tried. I'll try it right now and get back to you with the results. Thank you!

Comment: You can map the login to a Windows account as well.  Most times, people will have a service account on their domain to access the SQL resource, and will have the ApplicationPool identity that their application runs under impersonate that account.  Then you grant access for the database to that user.

Comment: So I created a new login, modified the line you wrote down, which btw for me is more like the following:  'connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\SecurityTutorials.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;"'
and did not work.  Still getting and authentication error with DOMAIN\username even though I changed the user ID and password like you suggested

Comment: Also, if I try to add a SQL Server Database to my project (on the App_Data folder) it gives me the same error:  Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\username'